# MYSQL - multiple SELECT statement in one Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables: users, posts, comments, and replies.

I want when Entering to user profile to get his posts where posts.user_id = users.user_id and comments where comments.post_id = posts.post_id and replies where replies.comment_id= comments.comment_id..

can all that done in the same statement Or I have to put a loop for comments inside the loop of posts and loop for replies inside the loop of comments?

**EDIT**

Here is the Code that I wanna Apply more simpler.. This code works fine and returns the post and and its owner and comments for the post and their owners and the replies for every comment and their owners..
But actually I want to do it with less loops.

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE 1");
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
    {
    $post_id=$row1['post_id'];
    $user = $row1['user_id'];
    $sql11 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id=$user");
        while($row11=mysql_fetch_array($sql11))
            {
                $username=$row11['user_name'];
            }
    echo("..post BY ". $username ."<br>");

    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id=$post_id");
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
    {
            $comment_id=$row2['comment_id'];
            $comment_user=$row2['user_id'];
               $sql21 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id=$comment_user");
                while($row21=mysql_fetch_array($sql21))
                {
                    $com_username=$row21['user_name'];
                }
        echo("......comment BY " . $com_username .  "<br>");

        $sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM replies WHERE comment_id=$comment_id");
        while($row3=mysql_fetch_array($sql3))
        {
                $rep_user=$row3['user_id'];
               $sql31 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id=$rep_user");
        while($row31=mysql_fetch_array($sql31))
            {
                $rep_username=$row31['user_name'];
            }
              echo("...........Reply BY ". $rep_username . "<br>");
        }

    }
}
```

[Here is the Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jitGI.png)

Comment: Use [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)s.

Comment: use join with specific where.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. You want to use the [MySQL JOIN syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

For example:

```
SELECT u.*, p.*, c.*, r.*
FROM users u
JOIN posts p ON u.user_id = p.user_id
JOIN comments c ON u.user_id = c.user_id
JOIN replies r ON u.user_id = r.user_id
```

Hopefully that give syou an idea on how to go about it.

Comment: and how to echo them if there are many replies for the same comment for example how fetching array can be done for replies of single comment?

Comment: That's a different question :) If you want replies for a given comment, just get replies for that comment: `SELECT * FROM replies r WHERE r.commentId = ?`. Try reading something like [this on W3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Comment: Simply, I want to: SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_user_id = user_id and for every post in that statement I want to:
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_post_id = post_id 
and same concept with replies

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables together without explicitly using the JOIN operator. Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users, 
       posts, 
       comments, 
       replies 
WHERE  posts.user_id = users.user_id 
       AND comments.post_id = posts.post_id 
       AND replies.comment_id = comments.comment_id
```

Comment: Please, always use the JOIN operator as it gives more clues to the optimizer what you want to happen. You can also add selection parameters to the 'JOIN ON...' query so that the optimizer can restrict the results before joining them to the other tables. ideally, you want the  `where` clause to be empty but still select all the rows you want. The `where` clause is the final filter for the result set rows.

Comment: @RyanVincent I agree with using the JOIN operator, but this is just an alternative.

Comment: The problem in JOIN operator is it will echo result only once..
In my case I want to echo more than one reply for the same comment and more than one comment for the same post..
How to approach this without all that loops In my code.

Comment: @AhmedElSayedSharafEldin,  it depends on the `join on` condition - you are not restricted to use `=`.  It can be any expression. Including `compound ones`.